# Animate dynamic list rows ranking using Vue.js

Tags: list, vue.js, nuxt.js

In my application I have a list with users playing a game, and sometimes users rank change. When data comes back from back-end every 10 seconds I tried animating using

```html
 <transition-group name="flip-list" tag="ul">
        <li v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item">
          {{ item }}
        </li>
</transition-group>
```

```css
.flip-list-move {
  transition: transform 1s;
}
```

But basically it renders the list with new items without any animations.
How to achieve that?

Comment: Hi, did you gave a read to this one? https://vuejs.org/guide/built-ins/transition-group.html#enter-leave-transitions

Comment: @kissu Hi, thanks for sharing. I did but basically my component gets re rendered without animations.